# Normalizing Flow ? Can somebody who knows about that write a tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tags

Question in title: [normalizing-flow](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normalizing-flow) needs a tag wiki ...

Comment: I'll take care of it.

Comment: Update: just submitted it. I don't have tag wiki edit privileges yet, so please take a look at that queue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to mark this as resolved—I submitted a tag wiki edit, and it’s been approved.

Comment: Thank you for a very nice tag wiki!

Comment: you may want to put this link on your answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/normalizing-flow/info

Comment: Seems redundant as it’s already in the question.